# Query accessing custom model method - Django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have 2 models that are relevant to this question:

```
class ParkingOrder(models.Model): # main order that could pay for multiple parkers
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, editable=False, primary_key=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    stripe_charge_id = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    wallet = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True) # if mobile wallet was used for order (Apple Pay, Google Pay, etc.)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    def walletdisplay(self):
        return self.wallet.replace('_', ' ').title()

class ParkingSession(models.Model): # attributes of a single parker
    parking_duration = models.ForeignKey(ParkingOption, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    parking_order = models.ForeignKey(ParkingOrder, on_delete=models.PROTECT) #refernce which order it belongs to
    price = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False) # store price in pennies
    license_num = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.parking_duration) + " - " + str(self.parking_order) + " - " + str(self.license_num)
```

I am trying to query a dictionary of all the wallet types.

```
ParkingSession.objects.filter(parking_order__status='Paid').exclude(parking_order__wallet='No wallet').values('parking_order__wallet').order_by('-parking_order__wallet').annotate(count=Count('parking_order__wallet'))
```

The above query works great but I want the walletdisplay method instead of the wallet attribute. This is because Stripe returns 'apple_pay', 'google_pay' instead of 'Apple Pay', 'Google Pay'.

I have tried this, but it throws an error saying that 'walletdisplay' is not an option:

```
ParkingSession.objects.filter(parking_order__status='Paid').exclude(parking_order__wallet='No wallet').values('parking_order__walletdisplay').order_by('-parking_order__walletdisplay').annotate(count=Count('parking_order__walletdisplay'))
```

How can I access the foreign key custom method in the query?

Comment: If you are just replacing the underscore then you could use a custom Func function to run a database level REPLACE function which would then allow you to call that Func whilst querying the queryset - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/

Comment: @SteveMapes That makes sense, however, I am also calling .title() so 'apple_pay' would become 'Apple Pay'. I do not see a way to do that on the database level with Func. Am I missing something?

Comment: So generally you can't use the logic in the method during the queryset call so you'd have to create a database level function to perform the case swapping. If you are using MySQL there are various examples online of UCWords style functions such as https://gist.github.com/Warloxk/a8e1cb3f50874364e17f6e3dc2c69103 but it'll still run code outside of Django. If you wanted to ensure the function exists you'd need to put it into a migration file to check and create the function